# Угадывание буквы

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
L=['самовар', 'весна', 'лето']

print(L)

b=input('Угадайте букву, которая есть в одном из этих слов: ')

import random

s=random.choice(L)
print(s)

a=random.choice(s)
print(a)

if a = b:
    print('ПОТРЯСАЮЩЕ! Вы угадали')
else:
    print ('Попробуйте еще разок')
```

Там где "a=b" пишет - 'invalid syntax'

Comment: замените  `if a = b:`  на `if a == b:`

Comment: Потому что у вас присваивание, а не сравнение, т.е. нужно: `if a == b:`

Comment: Ааа. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Детская ошибка, хотя и распостраненная)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

одинарное "=" это присваивание, для сравнения используйте "=="